# Transit visa in Japan

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, japan

I am travelling from US(SFO) to India (Delhi) via Haneda airport Japan. If my ANA flight from SFO to Haneda lands at Terminal T2 and my ANA flight from Haneda to Delhi is from terminal T3 , will I require transit visa to go from T2 to T3 at Haneda airport.

I do not have to collect my baggage at Haneda airport.

I am Indian citizen.

Answer (score 1):

In general if your air ticket doesn't ask you to do a self check in at the transit airport you don't have to worry about getting a transit visa. Since you don't have to collect your baggage at Haneda you should be good to go. For details about connections from T2 to T3 you can check out the following  [ANA website](https://www.ana.co.jp/en/jp/guide/prepare/airport-guide/international/hnd-transit/).

Comment: This is not a general worldwide advice,   in many countries people from some countries need transit visa even when they do not need to go through passport control and/or customs. Do you have proof people from India do not need a transit visa in Japan?

Comment: I think my point is different from what you are saying about requirement of transit visas in general. If they already transfer your luggage to the connecting flight doesn't it mean its within the transit zone and you can safely go through without a visa. That has always been my experience. Otherwise the airliner specifically mentions it during the purchase. Any ways I have an Indian passport and I am living in Japan and also used Haneda as a transit before and never had to get a transit visa.

Comment: If you are living in Japan you have the right visa to enter Japan. It is people who do not enter into the country who might need a transit visa, which will be checked by the airline before you get on the flight to Japan.

Comment: @MaharshiRay in many countries in Europe, Indian citizens will require an airport transit visa even if they stay airside and do not go through passport control (there are exceptions). In the US all transit passengers need a visa even if the luggage is checked through. Most airlines will not warn you and just rely on a “it’s up to you to know what documentation you need to have”.

Comment: @Willeke AFAIK Japan does not require transit visas for anybody with a connecting onward flight at the same airport.